# JS same-origin error with rutorrent, but only from one device

Tags: javascript, android, browser

This is an odd one...  I run rutorrent on a Ubuntu VPS for my media library.  Every device I connect to my rutorrent web interface works fine, except for my mobile, which throws this error:

`JS error: [https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/rutorrent/js/content.js : 72] Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

I've tried clearing browser settings, different browser on the phone (its Android btw), using a VPN (so IP is different) every time I get the above error when adding a torrent file.

ANY other device, no error...  Very strange, any ideas on where I should start in diagnosing this problem?

Comment: I'm having this same problem -- did you ever figure out a solution or workaround?

Comment: sadly no, I kinda gave up after a while, just having another look now... you have any luck?

Comment: Did some more testing - tried Chrome and Firefox on the device in question - first load = fine.  2nd load I get the error...  Really no idea why it does this with just one device, any other smartphone or tablet loads it just fine...